# Unit testing strategies for NHibernate Repository

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate, repository-pattern

I'm using NHibernate and the Repository pattern on a fairly large project and am trying to establish my service layer unit testing strategy and am having some problems getting in into my head. It's possible that I'm approaching the unit testing incorrectly, and it's also possible that I'm approaching the Repository pattern incorrectly, but I'm not sure which.

A simplified subset of my scenario looks like this:

```
public class UserRepository : RepositoryBase, IRepository 
{

   public UserRepository() {}
   public UserRepository( ISession sessionParam ) {
      session = sessionParam;   // member of repository base
   }

   public string GetUsernameFromEmail( string emailAddress ) {
      return session.QueryOver<Members>().List().Where( u => u.EmailAddress.ToLowerInvariant() == emailAdrress.ToLowerInvariant() ).FirstOrDefault().Username;
   }

}
```

My unit testing concept would be that I would fake NHibernate's ISession and pass in one that returned a list of users that would fit the scenario I'm trying to test (for instance, email address is case-insensitive) (I also can't get this to work with FakeItEasy, but that's for another question, should I proceed down this path).  Keeping in mind that we should not fake objects that we don't own, I can see the logic of not wanting to fake the ISession, and I've been reading a lot about how one shouldn't test the repository - that that's too far down for unit tests.

But even in this very basic case there's logic in the repository that I would like to unit test. Other repository methods will have potentially even more logic (data validation and the like, for instance). I know I can use SqlLite or something similar to build relatively fast integration tests for the reporitory, but it still seems to me that this logic should be unit tested.

Relying on the repository there is a (WCF) service tier that's being consumed by an Asp.Net MVC4 site.

In the best of all worlds I would build my unit tests in the WCF tier and fake away the IRepository for testing, but I don't see how I can move this logic to the service tier without  getting all of the users from the repository and returning them to the service tier, which seems ridiculous.

So my question is: what piece of the overall architecture here do I have fundamentally wrong in my head?

**EDIT**

In response to @Wiktor-zychla's answer, here's my logic regarding why I wanted to fake ISession. In thinking about this specific test, I want to have my repository use an implementation of ISession which always returns a single user with a mixed-case email address and a specfic username, pass in an all lower-case email address, and have the return value be the username I instructed my fake to use. That way I am testing my logic against a know value - whether or not that's how NHibernate will operate in the real world isn't my concern here - testing the logic in the repository method is. And again, I know this is a trivial and naive example that could be solved in many other ways - it's just standing in for more complicated functionality that I want to be able to test later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should try to fake the ISession. This doesn't make much sense - the NHibernate repository is a concrete implementation of an abstract concept and what you want to test is that whether or not this concrete implementation is ok rather than abstract it even further and test what? A different, fake linq implementation and then pretend that NH follows it?

Your unit tests should involve a real database then, probably set up before the test starts so that you inject a temp ISession to the repository but still the ISession points to a real database.

On the other hand, it is perfectly valid to have yet another implementation of the repository to be injected in your service layer when you test the service which uses the repository.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Wiktor. My concern is that once I introduce an actual database we're no longer talking about unit tests - those are integration tests, which I absolutely have to do, but that's not what I'm asking about here.

Comment: Not necessary. This is exactly one of edge cases where you need to think whether or not further abstractions make sense. My opinion on that (which I believe would be shared my a majority) would be that you can't reliably fake a linq provider and this is what would be necessary to unit test this. My answer is basically then "do not unit test this in a sense you seem to be attracted to".

Comment: From your comment I believe that you are trying to put too much responsibility into the repository layer. Non-trivial processing, validatiin etc should be done in upper layers thus making it easily testable. Think of it - would you DUPLICATE the same validation or processing logic in two or more implementations of the same repository interface?

Comment: That much I am willing to believe :-)

Comment: End result: I changed our repository model to be a lot more generic and to lazily filter the result set before returning it to the service layer and moved the logic into the service layer, mocking away the repositories as needed. Thanks!